# How to navigate to the Home Page after a successful Login using Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-getx

I have a Login Controller that does the action of loging in (with Google)

```
class LoginController extends GetxController {
  final _googleSignin = GoogleSignIn();
  var googleAccount = Rx<GoogleSignInAccount?>(null);

  login() async {
    googleAccount.value = await _googleSignin.signIn();
  }

  logout() async {
    googleAccount.value = await _googleSignin.signOut();
  }
}
```

Then I have a Log In UI that shows everything

```
final controller = Get.put(LoginController());
  LoginIn({
    super.key,
    required String title,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Sign-In Page')),
        body: Center(
          child: Obx(() {
            if (controller.googleAccount.value == null) {
              return loginButton(); //the Login button to log in with google
            } else {
              return seeProfile(); //after Login you are then able to see your profile
            }
          }),
        ));
  }
```

And then ofcourse I have a HomePage
How do I go to the Home Page after a successful log in

I tried to use ChatGPT and I did watch a couple of Youtube Videos but their code is ofcourse different then my and that makes it hard to implement their solution

Comment: I believe a cleaner way to do it would be to have  a streamBUilder which subscribes to FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(), and rebuilds the UI as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think checking the example in the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in/example)'s package on pub.dev might help you achieving what you want.

In summary, I would suggest you to listen to changes to the user in the `initState` method and push a new page after `signIn` is successful:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    StreamSubscription<GoogleSignInAccount?> subscription = _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
      if (account != null) {
        //push new screen
        Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(...)
        subscription.cancel()
      }
    });
  }
```

I couldn't test this code, but it should give you a general idea on how to proceed. Again, check the link above for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner method would be to use Stream builder and subscribe to the auth stream in the main.dart file. Based on the value, navigate the user.

'''
StreamBuilder<User?>(
initialData: null,
// stream: RepositoryProvider.of(context).authStream(),

```
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),

            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData &&
                  snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return HomePage();
                
                
              }
              
              return Container();
            });
```